# Why Coq doesn't allow a theorem with admits to end with QED in Linux and Windows?

Tags: coq, coqide, gallina

I am using Coq 8.10.0. Following proof script seems to work in Mac (ignoring warning):

```
Lemma plus_comm : forall (n m : nat), n + m = m + n.
Proof.
  intros.
  - admit.
Qed.
```

But the same proof script isn't accepted in Linux (Ubuntu) and Windows. It throws following error:

> (in proof plus_comm): Attempt to save a proof with given up goals. If
> this is really what you want to do, use Admitted in place of Qed.

Any idea what's going on here?

PS: I know ideally proofs with admits should end with Admitted instead of Qed/Defined. I am trying to debug a proof script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you are using the same Coq version on macOS and on the Windows/Linux? I don't remember exactly which version introduced a change in behaviour but now the default is to disallow `Qed` on a proof that is incomplete.

If you still want to debug a proof and need to use `Qed`, I would suggest using a temporary axiom:

```
Axiom todo : forall {A}, A.
Tactic Notation "todo" := (exact todo).
```

Now you can use `todo` as a tactic instead of `admit` and it will allow you to use `Qed`.

Comment: Yeah, that's a workable solution in my case. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

I just figured out it's not because of the operating system. It's because of **LibTactics** from Software Foundations (https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/plf-current/LibTactics.html). If we have **LibTactics** imported in Coq proof script, that allows us to put Qed at the end of a lemma with admits.

Comment: Then it might be that they redefine `admit` using the method I propose in my answer.

Comment: They might be using the same in LibTactics. I need to look into LibTactics for details.

Comment: Update: I am using an older version of LibTactics. Latest version of LibTactics doesn't have this special admissible behavior of admit and Qed.